# Changing name of keymap in Indicator Applet

Tags: 10.10, indicator, keyboard-layout

On my Ubuntu machine, I have two keymaps (US Dvorak and US QWERTY). Is there a way to change what they show up as in the Indicator Applet's layout switcher? e.g. DVK/QWR instead of USA/USA2

amit ron-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this post http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=3507927

> I finally found the solution. Edit the file `/etc/X11/xkb/rules/xorg.xml` . Around line 3164 (in my standard installation) replace all ocurances of USA with Eng. Voila, the keyboard indicator switches from Eng to Deu to Chi, the languages I use. No more USA!

Comment: Sort of works, but file was moved to /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules in Maverick, it seems.

Comment: This answer is useless without registering at the site referenced by the link.

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly, this is a hack.

I use the flags option in gconf-editor.  The flags merely represent each keyboard layout as the two letter designation rather than national flag images.  Currently, doing this causes all USA layouts to be represented with an image that has the letters "US".

I worked around this by using the Canadian keyboard layout as my Qwerty layout and USA-Dvorak as my Dvorak layout.  I then renamed the "US" icon ca.svg and created a new "DV" icon and named it us.svg.  The indicator now shows the proper layout.

The only problem I see is that when hovering, the tool-tip says "Canada English" when set to "US"